# How to validate user input in AppleScript

Tags: python-3.x, applescript

This is my first time with AppleScript, how do i add validation so that the user can't submit blank info in the input field?

```
firstname = """
display dialog "What is your name?" default answer "" ¬
buttons {"Submit"}
"""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example of how to make sure the user enters something:

```
set textReturned to ""
repeat while textReturned is equal to ""
    set textReturned to text returned of (display dialog ¬
        "What is your name?" buttons {"Submit"} ¬
        default button 1 default answer "")
end repeat
```

If you want to make sure what the user types is other then a *space* character (or pastes in a *tab* character) then add, e.g.:

```
if (do shell script "sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g'<<<" & ¬
    textReturned's quoted form) ¬
    is equal to "" then set textReturned to ""
```

So it would be, e.g.:

```
set textReturned to ""
repeat while textReturned is equal to ""
    set textReturned to text returned of (display dialog ¬
        "What is your name?" buttons {"Submit"} ¬
        default button 1 default answer "")
    if (do shell script "sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g'<<<" & ¬
        textReturned's quoted form) ¬
        is equal to "" then set textReturned to ""
end repeat
```